# How To Add An External Folder With Configurations To A Web Application In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, classpath

I created a normal Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. I added a folder to the project, which shows up after refreshing the project. The folder is containing an XML-file with configurations for the applications.

When I deploy the application on the tomcat in eclipse, the relative pathes do not match anymore. I need to copy the folder in the catalina home directory and then it works.

**Question**

*How can I add the folder to my project, that when I start tomcat (V7) in eclipse the folder is deployed as well and the relative pathes work too?*

When the development comes to an end, I will export a WAR-File and deploy it on my server. It would be great, if then the configurations will be included as well.

[image: Screenshot of Project folder]

If you have any questions or you need some further information, do not hesitate to ask nor to comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the configs-folder into the WebContent-folder and accorded the paths.
Now i have two configurations, one for my local execution and one for the execution on Tomcat after the deployment.

**Important Advise**

I needed to accord the filepaths starting from CATALINA's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the project's properties I have found where I can add the folder when I export the WAR-file. ***But it doesn't deploy in eclipse's tomcat yet. This part is still remaining.***

[image]